# Novel with 2 dimensions and to travel between you stared in a mirror and would cross over leaving a pool of quicksilver

Tags: story-identification, novel

There were 2 dimensions and the way to the alternate on was looking into a mirror and the person looking would go into the other world leaving a pool of quicksilver. I remember other things but at this point in time I am unsure if it is not from 2 different stories. But the children shuffled their feet since they had the ability to fly, there was a strong fear of mutation and the horses were huge.

I read this novel 50+ years ago.

Comment: Whilst a nice start is there anything else you can remember that you could [edit] in? See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) for some helpful pointers.

Answer (score 10):

I think you've definitely got at least three stories confused over the years. Apologies for partial answer

I can't identify the mirror story but I keep thinking Andre Norton.

---

The children who shuffle but can fly are characters in 'Pottage' (1955), a short story by Zenna Henderson, she had many short stories about The People - extraterrestrials who settled in America many years ago. Two main colonies were established and several scattered survivors following their colony ship crash landing.

In 'Pottage' a schoolteacher is assigned to the isolated community of Bendo. A cheerless town where the hidden alien  children are conditioned to shuffle in case they reveal a latent ability to levitate. This is due to savage attacks and killings generations earlier by the humans.

The teacher has previously worked in another secret alien town, Cougar Canyon, and so she is wise to the ways of the People and puts the two groups in contact.

---

You said "there was a strong fear of mutation and the horses were huge". This is from *The Chrysalids* (1955) by John Wyndham.

Many years post nuclear apocalypse, the community is continually seeking out mutants, they slaughter any animals but force human mutants into the Badlands.

There is considerable argument among the Elders over whether or not Shire horses (recently re-introduced into the community) are mutants due to their massive size in comparison to normal horses

Answer (score -1):

Zenna Henderson published a complete chronicle about "The People" which incorporated many of her stand-alone stories like those in "The Anything Box."
The chronicle tells why and how they were forced to leave their planet and how they were stranded on earth. I believe at the end of the chronicle, "The People" have a choice to go to the original planet they set out for or to stay on earth. There was also a really terrible movie based on her story about the children who shuffled starring William Shatner.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. The 'Your Answer' field should only be used to answer the question though, not to reply to previous answers. When you've earned enough [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege, you can leave comments beneath other users' questions or answers. In the meantime, you should focus on earning reputation by posting good questions or answers of your own. Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more.